# Saving selected lines in vim for running in conque

Tags: vim

I've started using conque+ipython+vim for python development, and one of things I'd like to do is be able to run chunks of text directly from vim. Using `<F9>` often fails when the code to be copied has blank lines or multiple levels of indentation.

I'm trying to write a vim function that:

1. Removes any common initial indentation from the currently selected lines (without modifying them in the buffer), then
2. Saves these modified lines to a temporary file, and
3. Writes a `%run file \n` to the conque buffer

but I've never coded vimscript before, and my understanding of vim's internals is patchy.

So far I have put together:

```
fun! runlines()
    let selectedlines = getbufline('%', line('<'), line('>'))

    " TODO : delete any initial indentation shared by all lines

    let temp = tempname().".py"
    call writefile(selectedlines, temp)

    " TODO: load into the conque buffer 

    au VimLeave * exe "!rm -f" temp
endfun
```

I think this should work if someone can offer guidance on how to complete the TODO blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython?
It has the ability to send lines or blockwise in visual mode.

Comment: I tried it initially, but it doesn't work with the setup on the server I'm using: I can't open an ipython session from within vim. I don't have the ability to muck around with the python or vim installations to fix whatever the issue is.